# international phone code for gravity form 'phone' fields

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to implement https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes/ with gravity form 'Phone' field. Problem is whenever there is validation error the dropdown disappears. I tried the following:

```
        $( '#ModalTrainingForm' ).on( 'shown.bs.modal', () => {
            const input = document.querySelector( '#input_3_5' );
            if ( input ) {
                window.intlTelInput( input, {
                    separateDialCode: true,
                    utilsScript: `../vendor/utils.js?${d}`,
                    autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
                    localizedCountries: { 'sv': 'Sweden' },
                });
            }
        });
```

along with

```
       $( document ).on( 'gform_post_render', () => {
            const input = document.querySelector( '#input_3_5' );
            if ( input ) {
                window.intlTelInput( input, {
                    separateDialCode: true,
                    utilsScript: `../vendor/utils.js?${d}`,
                    autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
                    localizedCountries: { 'sv': 'Sweden' },
                });
            }
        });
```

whenever there is gravity form validation error no option gets selected in dropdown. How to solve this? Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it's working now. Hope this helps someone.

```
        let instance = '';

        $( '#ModalTrainingForm' ).on( 'shown.bs.modal', () => { /* my form opens in popup */
            const input = document.querySelector( '#input_3_5' );
            if ( input ) {
                instance = window.intlTelInput( input, {
                    separateDialCode: true,
                    autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
                });
            }
        });

        $( document ).on( 'gform_post_render', ( e, formId ) => {
            if ( 3 === formId ) {
                const input = document.querySelector( '#input_3_5' );/* Phone field */
                if ( 0 !== $( 'div.validation_error' ).length ) {
                    instance.destroy();
                    const countryData = instance.getSelectedCountryData();
                    if ( input ) {
                        instance = window.intlTelInput( input, {
                            separateDialCode: true,
                            autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
                            initialCountry: countryData.iso2,
                        });
                    }
                }

                input.addEventListener( 'countrychange', () => {
                    instance.destroy();
                    const countryData = instance.getSelectedCountryData();
                    if ( input ) {
                        instance = window.intlTelInput( input, {
                            separateDialCode: true,
                            autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
                            initialCountry: countryData.iso2,
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```